# AmStock Chart based on non date as categoryAxis

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am trying to create a graph using AmStockChart version 2 the only thing which is not working is that I want to use numbers instead of date in category axis[image]

For this I have also added the below javascript but still ot working

```
var catAxis = new AmCharts.CategoryAxis();
catAxis.parseDates = false;
chart.categoryAxis = catAxis;
```

FULL JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
var stockPanel1 = new AmCharts.StockPanel();
stockPanel1.showCategoryAxis = true;
stockPanel1.recalculateToPercents = "never";

// Axis /////////////////////////////////////////////
var valAxis1 = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
valAxis1.position = "left";
valAxis1.inside = false;
valAxis1.gridAlpha = 1;
valAxis1.gridColor = "#ededee";
valAxis1.color = "#808285";

// Graph ///////////////////////////////////////////
var graph = new AmCharts.StockGraph();
graph.valueField = "Value";
graph.valueAxis = valAxis1;
graph.comparable = true;
graph.compareField = "Value";
graph.periodValue = "Open";
graph.lineThickness = 2;
graph.compareGraphLineThickness = 2;
stockPanel1.addStockGraph(graph);
stockPanel1.addValueAxis(valAxis1);
chart.panels = [stockPanel1];

// create stock legend                
var stockLegend1 = new AmCharts.StockLegend();
stockLegend1.valueWidth = 100;
stockLegend1.markerType = "line";
stockPanel1.stockLegend = stockLegend1;

//legend settings
var legendSettings = new AmCharts.LegendSettings();
legendSettings.markerBorderThickness = 6;
legendSettings.markerSize = 29;
legendSettings.color = "#808285";
chart.legendSettings = legendSettings;

// OTHER SETTINGS ////////////////////////////////////
var sbsettings = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbarSettings();
sbsettings.graph = graph;
sbsettings.backgroundColor = "#d5d7d8";
sbsettings.selectedBackgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
sbsettings.selectedGraphFillColor = "#dcdbb5";
sbsettings.color = "#808285";
sbsettings.enabled = false;
chart.chartScrollbarSettings = sbsettings;

//category settings
var catAxes = new AmCharts.CategoryAxesSettings();
catAxes.dashLength = 15;
catAxes.gridAlpha = 1;
catAxes.gridColor = "#dcddde";
catAxes.color = "#808285";

chart.categoryAxesSettings = catAxes;

chart.panelsSettings.marginRight = 50;
chart.panelsSettings.marginLeft = 50;


var catAxis = new AmCharts.CategoryAxis();
catAxis.parseDates = false;
chart.categoryAxis = catAxis;

//Changes cursor from red to green
var cursorSettings = new AmCharts.ChartCursorSettings();
cursorSettings.cursorColor = "#8e8c35";
cursorSettings.width = 3;
cursorSettings.zoomable = false;
chart.chartCursorSettings = cursorSettings;
chart.write('chartdiv');
```

Please let me know if you need any more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem by starting the category axis from year 2000 and then adding 1.
In amchart changed the setting to display the last two characters of year

```
var catAxes = new AmCharts.CategoryAxesSettings();
catAxes.dateFormats = [{ period: 'fff', format: 'JJ:NN:SS' }, { period: 'ss', format: 'JJ:NN:SS' }, { period: 'mm', format: 'JJ:NN' }, { period: 'hh', format: 'JJ:NN' }, { period: 'DD', format: 'DD' }, { period: 'WW', format: 'MMM DD' }, { period: 'MM', format: 'YY' }, { period: 'YYYY', format: 'YY'}];
chart.categoryAxesSettings = catAxes;
```

Answer (score 1):

Stock chart can not work with non-date-based category axis. You can use AmXYChart instead.